# action delete with request page not exist

Tags: php, view, yii2

Hi i want to remove some data. I do view where i want to delete aditional data. This is my controller veiew becouse i want to make there button where i can delete data:

```
 public function actionView($id) {

        return $this->render('view', [
                    'model' => $this->findModel($id),
                    'userDate'=>$this->findData($id)
        ]);
    }


 public function actionDelet($id) {

    $this->findData($id)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}

public function findData($id){
     if (($model = Profile::findOne($id)) !== null) {
         $id=$model->Rel_UserData;
         $user = UserData::find()->where(['Id' => $id])->one();

        return $user;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not st.');
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe you need flush after delete.

Comment: when I point the mouse over the button shows me this id with the id in the table so i dont know why its wrong

Comment: there is only rules look my edited post

Answer (score 0):

I guess solution is like that:

```
$item = $this->findData($id);
$item->delete();
```

Comment: where i should put that?

Comment: i put it in my actionDelet and it still the same

Comment: Change your actionDelet method contents.

Comment: i change and have no effect :(

Comment: So, delete item after assign item a variable

Comment: how can i delete item after assign

Comment: i said that before you try.

Comment: i cant underrstand, can u edit Your answer and show me example? Please

Answer (score 0):

You already have a relational function calling the `UrRoyalUserData` class: `getRelRoyalUserData()`. You can simplify your code doing:

```
public function findData($id)
{
    if (($model = Profile::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        $user = $model->relRoyalUserData;

        return $user;
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not st.');   
}
```

Besides that, can you change your action and check what is returning?

```
public function actionDelet($id)
{    
    var_dump($this->findData($id));
}
```

If it throws you the same error, that means you dont have that `Profile` in your table. But if don't return a UrRoyalUserData class, the problem is you don't have any `UrRoyalUserData` related to that `Profile`.